# Parse hashtags in a string, except for anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, hashtag

I would like to convert any instances of a hashtag (`#`) in a given string into a HTML tag:

For example:

- `#test` should convert to `<a>#test</a>`
- `test#test` should not convert
- `<a href="#test">#test</a>`  should not convert
- `<p>#test</p>` should become `<p><a>#test</a></p>`
- `<b>#test</b>` should become `<b><a>#test</a></b>`

Comment: Have you tried anything? Hint: check the character before the `#`.

Comment: Looks like you haven't made an attempt

Comment: [regular expression on HTML is a no no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Hint: `^` is the beginning of a string and `[^>]` is `!= '>'`.

Comment: Rule 1: don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with RegEx, see rule 1.  [RegEx can only match regular languages, and HTML is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/930393)

Comment: @epascarello: You beat me to it :P

Comment: @JayHarris Neither of those should convert, according to the examples.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yeah i just read it again. i thought it was a username thing

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following could be a start (tested in vim):

```
:% subst :<[^>|a>]\+>\zs\(#[^<]\+\)\ze:<a>\1</a>:
```

It would meet your last three requirements.

As for the first two, they are too broad, I guess, especially because of `test#test`. I am at work and can't spend much time on this now.

By the way, as people said, regexps should not be used to parse html/xml stuff. Perhaps it is still OK if it is to learn and study, though.

EDIT: This other regex matches the first two requirements:

```
%s:\(\w\|<[^>]\+>\|"\)\@<!\(#[^ ]\+\):<a>\2<\/a>:
```

It will add `<a>` around #hashtag up to the first white space. That would have to be adapted according to the possibilities your situation requires. It is matching #hashtags when they do not appear after html tags, word characters (teste#teste wouldn't match) or double quotes (for attributes). You could have to add single quotes as well or other possibilities.

It was a nice exercise (during lunch time...) but do follow the advices people gave you in their comments.

Answer (score 0):

**RegEx you need is**

`(<[\w]+>#test<\/[\w]+>)|^(#test)|(\s#test)|(\s#test$)`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mX1rU2)

**Code**

```
var str = '#test test#test #test har #test <a href="#test">#test</a> <p>#test</p> <b>#test</b> <pre>#test</pre> #test char #test'

//str.match(/(<[\w]+>#test<\/[\w]+>)|^(#test)|(\s#test)|(\s#test$)/g)
//["#test", " #test", " #test", "<p>#test</p>", "<b>#test</b>", "<pre>#test</pre>", " #test", " #test"]

str.replace(/(<[\w]+>#test<\/[\w]+>)|^(#test)|(\s#test)|(\s#test$)/g, function($1) {
return $1.replace('#test','<a>#test</a>')
})
```

**Output**

```
<a>#test</a> test#test <a>#test</a> har <a>#test</a> <a href="#test">#test</a> <p><a>#test</a></p> <b><a>#test</a></b> <pre><a>#test</a></pre> <a>#test</a> char <a>#test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html, there is a simple way to do this.

This problem is a classic case of the technique explained in this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)

We can solve it with a beautifully-simple regex:

```
\w#test|<a.*?</a>|(#test)
```

All the left sides of the alternation  `|` match complete `#test` in unwanted contexts. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures `#test` to Group 1, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

This program shows how to use the regex. Note that **for the demo I have replaced with `[a]` instead of `<a>` so the results are visible in the browser**. See the results in the right pane of the [online demo](http://js.do/code/39875)):

```
var subject = ' yesSingle #test  no test#test no <a href="#test">#test</a> yesParagraph <p>#test</p> yesBold <b>#test</b>';
var regex = /\w#test|<a.*?<\/a>|(#test)/g;
replaced = subject.replace(regex, function(m, group1) {
    if (group1 == "" ) return m;
    else return "[a]" + group1 + "[/a]";
});
document.write(replaced);
```

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)